# Julia Pkg.update() and LibGit2 trouble

Tags: julia

I can't do `Pkg.update()` or `Pkg.add("Something")` behind my office firewall, though with the following in `~/.gitconfig` I can use git to clone from the command line with cntlm running on my local machine

```
[http]
    proxy = 127.0.0.1:3128
    sslVerify = false
[url "https://"]
    insteadOf = git://
```

I get the following error in Julia 0.6.2 (below). Any ideas? I'm dead in the water now with package management. It seems LibGit2 isn't picking up the `sslVerify=false` statement (which I know is a bad idea and shouldn't regularly be used)

```
julia> Pkg.update()
INFO: Updating METADATA...
ERROR: METADATA cannot be updated. Resolve problems manually in /blah/julia_packages/v0.6/METADATA.
GitError(Code:ECERTIFICATE, Class:SSL, SSL error: ffffd900[8] - X509 - Certificate verification failed, e.g. CRL, CA or signature check failed)
macro expansion at ./libgit2/error.jl:99 [inlined] #fetch#41(::Base.LibGit2.FetchOptions, ::String, ::Function, ::Base.LibGit2.GitRemote, ::Array{AbstractString,1}) at ./libgit2/remote.jl:226
(::Base.LibGit2.#kw##fetch)(::Array{Any,1}, ::Base.LibGit2.#fetch, ::Base.LibGit2.GitRemote, ::Array{AbstractString,1}) at ./<missing>:0 ...
```